# unable to render text to DOM from state vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to render a name to my component, which I get from an axios response. I am able to print the name in the console but `{{username}}` is never updated.

```
setup() {
        const state = reactive({
            username: '',
        })

        const submit = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await api.getTest()

                if (response != null) {
                    state.username = response.name
                    console.log("I am the state " + state.username)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error while getting the response:', error)
            }
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            submit
        }
    },
```

template

```
<template>
    <button v-on:click="submit()" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
        Button
    </button>
    <div class="text-white">
        Name: {{username}}
    </div>

</template>
```

1. why is the username not updating?
2. is this the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a reactive object, so you have to use that object in the template. `username` is not defined in the template scope, it would be `{{state.username}}`.

One other approach would be to define the username as a ref, but then you have to set it's value:
`const username = ref('');`
And in the async function:
`username.value = response.name`